# Binomial theorem relating proof

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There is this identity

$$1 -\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{1}+\frac{1}{3} \binom{n}{2}- \frac{1}{4}\binom{n}{3}+....+(-1)^n \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n}{n}$$

And we are supposed to prove it using these two identities

$$k\binom{n}{k} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

and

$$\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} +....+ \binom{n}{n} = 2^n$$

I have been working on this problem for a long time.  Can you guys help me?

Comment: Your first expression?

Comment: Is this correct as written? I do not see an equality to prove

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{i+1}= \int_0^1 x^i dx
\end{eqnarray*}
Sub this into the sum & interchange the order of the sum & the integral
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i\binom{n}{i} \frac{1}{i+1}&=& \int_0^1  \sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i\binom{n}{i}x^i dx \\
&=& \int_0^1  (1-x)^n dx \\
&=&  \left[  \frac{-(1-x)^n}{n+1} \right]^1_0 \\
&=&   \color{blue}{ \frac{1}{n+1}}  \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Your answer is better than mine+1).

Answer (score 6):

\begin{eqnarray}
&&1 - \frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{1}+\frac{1}{3} \binom{n}{2}- \frac{1}{4}\binom{n}{3}+....+(-1)^n \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n}{n}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k}\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k}\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}\\
&=&\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k}\binom{n+1}{k}\\
&=&-\frac{1}{n+1}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{k}\binom{n+1}{k}-1\right]\\
&=&\frac1{n+1}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: $\pm \frac{1}{n+1}$ ... lol ... I was about to change my answer to agree with yours $\ddot \smile$

Comment: Your answer uses the binomial identity we are instructed to use and is therefore probably the solution that is required.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit, thanks.

Comment: why the last line? The final step? Oh the sum fluctuating combinatoric is 0? what about if n is odd?

Comment: @J.Chang, use $(1-1)^{n+1}=0$.

Comment: I think you need to be more explicit on that last step. He he he he.

Comment: @J.Chang, I omitted.